# when should you employ the POST method over the GET method for submitting data from a form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

when should you employ the POST method over the GET method for submitting data from a form?

1-when you want the data to be cached
2- when efficiency is important
3- when the data in the form may be sensitive
4- when you want to use your browser to help with debugging

and explain the answer please

Comment: This sounds like a homework question; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Using the GET method when submitting form data will place all information submitted in the form as readable text in the navigation bar of the browser. That doesn't sound too secure to me, especially with sensitive information.